# Java - force implemented interface to extend a class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

I'm trying create the following structure in a GWT application, though this is really a Java issue:

1. `ChatComponent` is a marker interface, has no methods in it; it is meant to mark components that can comprise a `ChatMessage`.
2. All chat components are widgets, but it's unknown what kind exactly; I want to allow chat components to extend whatever they want.
3. However, I also want all chat components to be some extension of Widget and have this reflected in code.

Basically what I want is to be able to say

```
List<Widget> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ChatComponent());
```

Now the problem here is obvious, interfaces cannot extend classes and I can't use an abstract class, because I want the component classes to be able to extend whatever they want; so I can't just subclass `Widget` in an abstract and then extend that.

Is there a neat way to do this? If it can't be done in the class hierarchy, but can be done in only methods with generics and wildcards, that would work for me too, but I couldn't really figure out a good way to do that either.

Comment: If ChatComponent is an interface, you wouldn't be able to use the code new ChatComponent()

Answer (score 0):

It may work to use generic wildcards.  Create a ChatComponent interface.

```
List<? extends ChatComponent> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyChatComponent());
```

MyChatComponent.class should be a Widget and  implement the ChatComponent interface.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, you can't add to a list with a wildcard like that at all.

Comment: Huh, you're right!  I always thought that worked, I guess I hadn't tried it with a list.